# comparing two arrays and printing the inex of the first array

Tags: java, arrays

hi im new to java and i want to compare two arrays from user input

```
enter the number of values in array : 5

  3 6 8 10 11
 enter the number of values in array : 4

   5 10 3 11

 output
 
     1 4 1 5
```

if element present in array 1 is also present in array 2, then print the index in array 1 if not ( in case of 5) , greatest values less than 5, then print its index

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

 class GFG {

// function to create hashsets
// from arrays and find
// their common element
public static void FindCommonElements(int[] arr1,
                                      int[] arr2)
{
    // create hashsets
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();

    // Adding elements from array1
    for (int i : arr1) {
        set1.add(i);
    }

    // Adding elements from array2
    for (int i : arr2) {
        set2.add(i);
    }

    // use retainAll() method to
    // find common elements
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    System.out.println("Common elements- " + set1);
}

// main method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create Array 1
    int[] arr1
        = { 3, 6, 8, 10, 11 };

    // create Array 2
    int[] arr2 = { 5, 10, 3, 11 };

    // print Array 1
    System.out.println("Array 1: "
                       + Arrays.toString(arr1));
    // print Array 2
    System.out.println("Array 2: "
                       + Arrays.toString(arr2));
    FindCommonElements(arr1, arr2);
}
```

}

how can i find and print the index rather than the values.

Comment: what is the expected output from this program ? that is not clear , 
if  element present in array 1 is also present in array 2, then print the index in array 1 
if not ( in case of 5) , greatest values less than 5, then print its index , 
is this what you want ?

Comment: yes thats the exact thing i need.

Comment: please share something that you tried

Comment: added currently im able to only compare and print the same elements but i want to compare and print the index of the matchung elements and index of the greatest element if the match is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare each element of array 2 with each element of array 1 and in case , the value is present in array 1, then you can store that index value in it ( since you are storing based on 1-based index, i'm adding 1 to the indices ) and for elements not present, you can check if the value is greater than the value of array1 element, and in case it is , you need to check if it is greater than the last maxium ( for example, if 5 is present in array2 , and 3,4 are present in array1 ,then it should store the index of element 4 and not 3 )

```
public class ArrayComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[] = { 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 4 };
        int arr2[] = { 5, 10, 3, 11 };
        int res[] = findingIndex(arr1, arr2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
    }

    private static int[] findingIndex(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int res[] = new int[arr2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            int index = 0;
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                if (arr2[i] > arr1[j]) {
                    if (arr1[j] > max) {
                        index = j + 1;
                        max = arr1[j];
                        res[i] = index;
                    }

                } else if (arr2[i] == arr1[j]) {
                    res[i] = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
[6, 4, 1, 5]
```